# Error at every shutdown with Linux mint and MSI gaming laptop

Tags: linux

I've got an MSI GL73-8RD with Linux Mint as the OS. My computer takes a very long time at every shutdown and displays this:

[image: Photo1]

I don't know where is the problem... Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: What version of Mint? What kernel version?

Comment: Linux mint 19.2 Cinnamon and 4.15.0-65-generic for the kernel

Comment: Try the latest 5.0 kernel.